# Hide an Unordered List on loss of focus with jquery

Tags: jquery

My Unordered list is hidden by default but appears when the user clicks on the button. The problem is when I move off the unordered list I want the entire thing to hide/disappear. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#aboutUsFlyOut').click(function () {
            $('.flyOutMenu').slideToggle('medium');
        });
    });

</script>

<a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;"><img id="aboutUsFlyOut" src="../../button.png" alt="About Us" /></a>        
<ul class="flyOutMenu">
    <li><a href="">menu item 1<a></li>
    <li><a href="">menu item 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="">menu item 3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="">menu item 4</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I move off the unordered list I want the entire
>   thing to hide/disappear.

You can attach a `mouseleave` event to the `ul` and toggle it back up again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aboutUsFlyOut').click(function() {
        $('.flyOutMenu').slideToggle('medium');
    });

    $('ul.flyOutMenu').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).slideToggle('medium');
    });
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ecEmg/) - hide list on mouseleave

In response to `Juan Mendes`'s comment I added a variation which waits 2 seconds before hiding it again in case the user hovers back over it with the mouse.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseHasEntered = false;

    $('#aboutUsFlyOut').click(function() {
        $('.flyOutMenu').slideToggle('medium');
    });

    $('ul.flyOutMenu').on('mouseenter', function() {
        mouseHasEntered = true;
    });

    $('ul.flyOutMenu').on('mouseleave', function() {
        var $list = $(this);

        mouseHasEntered = false;

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!mouseHasEntered) {
                $list.slideToggle('medium');

                // or use $list.hide() if you don't want it to animate.
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/Lvc9G/) - hide list on mouseleave with a delay in case mouse re-enters

Comment: This is usually implemented with a timeout, hide the popup one or two seconds after the `mouseleave`, if another `mouseenter` doesn't fire within that time.

Comment: @JuanMendes: That makes sense. I like common practice and if this is what usually would be done the better. I added an alternative, including a timeout, checking if the mouse has re-entered. I don't know what the common standard way of implementing this usually is but the code seems to work for now. Feel free to add any suggestion on improving this. Thanks again for the comment. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `mouseout` and hide the menu if it is visible:

```
var menu = $('.flyOutMenu');
$('#aboutUsFlyOut').on('click', function () {
    menu.slideToggle('medium');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    if(menu.is(':visible')
        menu.slideToggle('medium');
});
```

You may need to add some more checks to make sure the menu is not currently animating.